# copy_from_user returns error

Tags: linux, copy, kernel

I'm trying to create a store function for a sysfs file that holds the integer "timer_interval" (a global variable).

```
static ssize_t sys_store(struct kobject *kobj, struct kobj_attribute *attr, const char *buf,     size_t count)
{
  printk(KERN_ALERT "BUF IS %s and count is %d", buf, count);
  int ret;

  char *pTemp = kmalloc(100, GFP_KERNEL); 
  if (pTemp == NULL) 
  {
     printk(KERN_ALERT "malloc WRONG");
     return -EFAULT;
  }

  printk(KERN_ALERT "AFTER MALLOC");

  if (ret = copy_from_user(pTemp ,buf, count)) 
  {
    printk(KERN_ALERT "COPY WRONG %d", ret);
    kfree(pTemp);
    printk(KERN_ALERT "%d" , pTemp);
    return -EFAULT;
  }

  printk(KERN_ALERT "AFTER COPY");

  if (sscanf(pTemp, "%d", &Timer_interval) < count);
  {
    printk(KERN_ALERT "SCANF WRONG");
    kfree(pTemp);
    return -EFAULT;
  }

  printk(KERN_ALERT "AFTER SCANF COUNT = %d", Timer_interval);
  kfree(pTemp);
  return count;
}
```

The problem is on copy to user. the dmesg shows that the allocation is fine, the buf contains the correct data, but copy_from_user returns the size of the buffer, meaning nothing was copied.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried to replace ```const char *buf``` with ```const char __user *buf```? This is a hint that buf is an address in user space. I met the same problem when I declared a function, in which it called ```copy_from_user``` or ```__get_user```, etc. Such function worked fine in ioctl, but did not work outside ioctl. Both  ```copy_from_user``` and ```__get_user``` failed.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely `buf` is a kernel space pointer and you don't need to use `copy_from_user`. copy_from_user is called by kernel.

**UPDATE.**

`buf` is direct buffer from user. And you should check buf's data for correctness. For example, function could be called with text while it expects numbers.

BTW. You don't check what pTemp array contains null terminator before sscanf call.
And if you copy the buffer you need to check the size of src and dst buffers to prevent memory corruption or segfaults.

Comment: The buf is the direct input from the user... I'm pretty sure it needs to be checked. can anyone confirm?